# How to disable URL tooltip (status bar)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

When I click on a link (or hover with a mouse), the URL shows up at the bottom of the screen. That's the default behaviour in Firefox.

How can I prevent this ?

I'm making a website for tactile interfaces.

Thanks !

Comment: have you tried using jquery..?

Comment: how can I use jquery for this ?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would imagine its because this is very much bad practice.  The status bar is there to stop dodgy sites trying to fool people by linking to pages other than that written on the screen.

Comment: Then, the one that downvoted should have asked me the reason why... It's for an Interactive kiosk and the client doesn't want any visible URL. The page should look like an app.

Comment: Here is just a thought, if you really need to control this behavior, don't use firefox. Consider embedding a form of webview in whatever application language where you can control the chrome and behavior of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you are using any other tag other than `<a>` if suppose you are using a

`<div id='idofdiv'>` tag

the query will be

```
$('#idofdiv').click(function(){
window.open('www.google.com');
});
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, I thought about this... If there's no way to disable URL tooltips, I'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this using jquery,
first inlcude the jquery library in your page then

write the script in the page

```
 $(function(){
       $('[data-url]') //select all elements having data-url
        .click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
         window.location.href= $(this).attr('data-url')})
    })
```

**and in the html**

```
<span data-url="#/inbox" >Go to inbox</span>
<a data-url="mydraft.html">Drafts</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don`t show what object will do onClick, so try this:

```
<div onclick="location.href ='http://www.google.com';"> click me </div>
```

Or you can use span which is inline element:

```
<span onclick="location.href ='http://www.google.com';"> click me </span>
```

Comment: As said @Ahmad , I can also still use `<a>` and only remove the href attribute (it will change its behaviour to a classic span one).

Comment: By the way, if you won`t use href in a, you won`t be able to manage style for visited links.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and CSS is nowhere here, you just cannot do it with CSS, well you can use something like this to spoof the `<a>` link but I suggest you don't use all this, without any specific reason, anyways they'll find the URL from the source page

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href ='http://www.google.com';">Spoofing</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cCU4/)

Note: Actually just checked, the demo is not working on the fiddle page but just make a local `.html` page and it will work

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, actually all my links already have `href="#"`. It displays "http://mysite.com/mypage.php#". And no they won't/shouldn't see any URL, as my page has a Javascript-only navigation in full screen.

Comment: @theredled you wont get another answer for this, so better don't downvote correct answers, if you do get a better solution, do let me know

Comment: I appreciate your effort of answering and making a fiddle page, but how is this a correct answer ?

Comment: @theredled I already said it is not possible, doesn't that say its correct? actually you tagged it as `CSS` and you wanted a CSS solution, so these answers are bonus as I re-tagged your question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the word "spoof". So yes, this answer is correct even if it doesn't fill my needs.

Comment: exactly, I don't mind but I gave answer according to your tagged question which was CSS so there's is no way you can do that with CSS ..