# Get rid of link label?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I'm not really sure how to ask this in words, but is there any way I could get rid of the little "pop-up" at the bottom of the browser when hovering over a link? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8QIO.png)'s what I was to eliminate  the little thing at the bottom with `google.com` current in it. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: Not really? Does that mean absolutely "no" or is there some extremely complicated way to do it? @adeneo

Comment: Incidentally, it's generally called the "status bar". Allowing you to remove it would be a rather odd thing for a browser to do; a bit like removing the "back" button, or the URL bar.

Comment: Why do you want to hide a link from the user?

Comment: I want to hide it because it covers the home link

Comment: So is there any way I can swap pages with JS? Instead of HTML @IMSoP

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293480/how-to-disable-url-tooltip-status-bar)

Comment: A JS link in order to stop a status bar temporarily overlapping another link (one which the user is, by definition, not hovering over)? Sounds like a sledgehammer to crack a nut to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really think of any "honest" reason for doing this, but if you've found one, it is possible by doing something like this with your link(s) in the HTML:

```
<a id="link-trigger" href="#">Link</a>
```

And then injecting the destination when the link is clicked:

```
$('#link-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location('http://domain.com');
}
```

The only time I've encountered this is when a website is trying to disguise where it is sending the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security risk. Therefore you can't disable with your code (JQuery/ JavaScript). But, this doesn't mean you can't trick the browser :-D

Here's a tip. I beleive your problem is when you hover over your "Home" link at the bottom of your page the URL belongs to that is shown in the status bar of the browser. If this is the case. Try something like this.

Add a link to your "Home" link as follows. This calls a JavaScript function, which indirectly redirects the URL you want.

```
<a href="#" onClick="yourFunc(); return false;">Home</a>
```

Since there's no value in "href" the browser don't have anything to show in the status bar.

Try it and let me know how it goes.

All the best!

Comment: `there's no value in "href" the browser don't have anything to show`. Browsers aren't *that* dumb, the status bar will likely show the URL of the current page (since that's what `#` represents).

Comment: @RobG: I didn't say browsers are dumb. And, you are just guessing here. Have you tried this? Do you see a URL? href="#" means current page. I know that. But, that doesn't mean it'll be shown in the status bar.

Comment: "Do you see a URL?" Yes, in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Safari shows "Go to # on this page", so 3 out of 4 show a URL, hence "likely", and all show something so "don't have anything to show" isn't exactly on the money. :-)